# How to avoid double quotes adding up to Author metadata field while editing using iTextSharp in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, itext

How to avoid double quotes adding up to Author metadata field while editing using iTextSharp in C#?

e.g. I am passing author1;author2 to iTextSharp but after editing done.
PDF metadata shows "author1;author2"

Comment: This was fixed a while ago, wasn't it? Are you by any chance using an old version of iText? Please test the most recent version and tell us if the problem persists.

Comment: Although this behaviour is not seen with Keywords metadata field.

Comment: Hi I am using iTextSharp ver 5.5.4

Comment: I'll test with iText 5.5.4 and take a look at what happens.

Comment: Now I see, the problem doesn't occur when you have "author 1 author 2", only when you have "author 1; author 2". I'll investigate.

Comment: Yes this is the issue. Let me know how to fix.

Comment: I just found the issue. We can fix it in iText(Sharp). You can only fix it if you fix the iTextSharp code and create a new DLL. If you can't do that, you'll have to wait for the next release.

Comment: I have the code. Let me know where to fix this, in the code. I can create a new DLL for the same.

Comment: You need to fix the `addDocInfoProperty` method in the `XmpWriter` class. Right now it creates XML like this: `<dc:creator><rdf:Seq><rdf:li>fox, dog</rdf:li></rdf:Seq></dc:creator>`. You need to change it so that it creates XML like this: `<dc:creator><rdf:Seq><rdf:li>fox</rdf:li><rdf:li>dog</rdf:li></rdf:Seq></dc:creator>`

Comment: I've made a ticket with number DEV-1244 in our internal issue tracker. Let us know when you've fixed this and refer to the ticket number so that whichever engineer at iText gets your message knows where to find the ticket.

Comment: I tried to edit the code but unfortunately couldn't rectify the issue. is it possible to send me patch of code so that I can try?

Comment: I've made an internal ticket with number DEV-1244. This ticket has a low priority, so I don't know when the issue will be fixed. I'll add a comment explaining that you won't fix it and that whichever engineer has time to fix it should post the solution here.

Comment: This is the patch: http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/6737 Note that your problem can't be solved if you need PDF/A. The actual problem is caused by Adobe Acrobat / Reader. We can't fix idiosyncrasies introduced by Adobe.

Comment: I see that my changes have broken some tests. We may decide not to keep the fix and to tolerate the quotes that are added by Adobe when you look at the metadata. My "fix" removes data in order to make Adobe show the data the way **you** want. However, it is Adobe reader that should show the data **correctly**. Please file a bug report with Adobe so that they can fix this.

Comment: I have one question in another metadata field - Keywords. It shows no double quotes if I enter  like this- keyword1; keyword 2. Also please provide the fix in C# too.

Comment: As the "fix" breaks PDF/A conformance, it won't be accepted in iText. As such, it won't be ported to C#. As for the keywords, you'll notice that the situation is different: keywords are stored twice in the XMP metadata.

Comment: Thanks for all the insights.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

I have sent this question to Adobe and I received an answer almost immediately:

> The quotes are a long standing issue, but are 100% correct and there for a reason.  They help differentiate “Lowagie, Bruno” as a single entry vs. Lowagie, Bruno showing up as two separate authors.

Now that I understand the reason for adding the quotes, I have done some further investigation and I use this answer to share my findings with Adobe:

**Adapted answer:**

Currently, iTextSharp implements your request like this:

- Add `(Author 1; Author 2)` as an `/Author` entry to the info dictionary.
- Add `<dc:creator><rdf:Seq><rdf:li>Author 1, Author 2</rdf:li></rdf:Seq></dc:creator>` in the XMP metadata stream.

As a result, Adobe Acrobat / Reader show the metadata like this:

```
"Author 1; Author 2"
```

In other words: Adobe adds double quotes. This can be checked here: [no_distinction_between_authors.pdf](http://itextpdf.org/documents/pdfa/no_distinction_between_authors.pdf)

There are two disadvantages to this approach:

1. Adobe Acrobat / Reader adds double quotes.
2. It's as if there is only one author. If double quotes are to be added, one would expect "Author 1"; "Author 2".

**Why you may think it's an iTextSharp bug:**

One would expect that iText adds the names of the authors like this:

- Add `(Author 1; Author 2)` as an `/Author` entry to the info dictionary.
- Add `<dc:creator><rdf:Seq><rdf:li>Author 1</rdf:li><rdf:li>Author 2</rdf:li></rdf:Seq></dc:creator>` in the XMP metadata stream.

This certainly looks more correct than before, because you now have two list items for two authors instead of a single list item for two authors.

Unfortunately, Adobe Acrobat / Reader now display the names of the authors like this:

```
"Author 1; Author 2"; Author 2
```

This looks totally wrong, but if you look inside the PDF (under the hood), all data is correct. This is demonstrated here: [display_not_OK_pdfa_broken.pdf](http://itextpdf.org/documents/pdfa/display_not_OK_pdfa_broken.pdf)

There are two disadvantages to this approach:

1. The display of the author in the Document Properties dialog is odd.
2. This approach breaks PDF/A.

**How to solve this problem to make Adobe Acrobat / Reader happy:**

One can make Adobe Acrobat / Reader display the authors correctly like this:

- Add `(Author 1)` as an `/Author` entry to the info dictionary.
- Add `<dc:creator><rdf:Seq><rdf:li>Author 1</rdf:li><rdf:li>Author 2</rdf:li></rdf:Seq></dc:creator>` in the XMP metadata stream.

Now when you look at the metadata in Adobe Acrobat / Reader, you see:

```
Author 1; Author 2
```

This is actually what Adobe Acrobat does when you manually add a couple of authors, separated by a semi-colon. The quotes have gone and all looks fine on the outside.

This is demonstrated in:

- [display_OK_pdfa_broken.pdf](http://itextpdf.org/documents/pdfa/display_OK_pdfa_broken.pdf) created by iText, and
- [hello_acrobat.pdf](http://itextpdf.org/documents/pdfa/hello_acrobat.pdf), a file to which I added metadata using Acrobat (in other words: this is how Adobe expects you to do it).

A major disadvantage to this approach, is that you can not meet PDF/A compliance when using this approach. If you look at what we've changed, you see that we removed Author 2 from the info dictionary, whereas we keep Author 2 in the XMP metadata.

Not only does remove information (actually, that's not so bad because XMP gets priority over the info dictionary), but this is also not allowed in the context of PDF/A: the metadata in the info dictionary needs to be identical to the metadata in the XMP stream or PDF/A validation fails in Adobe Acrobat.

In my opinion, Acrobat is doing it wrong.

**My suggestion for Adobe:**

Take a look at [correct_but_display_not_OK_pdfa_broken.pdf](http://itextpdf.org/documents/pdfa/correct_but_display_not_OK_pdfa_broken.pdf).

When I look inside the PDF, the data does seem to reflect what one would expect in the real world:

- The Author entry in the Info dictionary looks like this: `"Author 1"; "Author 2"`. Even if there was punctuation in the name of the author, the distinction between different authors would be correct. This is in line with the explanation I received from Adobe.
- In the XMP metadata, we have `<dc:creator><rdf:Seq><rdf:li>Author 1</rdf:li><rdf:li>Author 2</rdf:li></rdf:Seq></dc:creator>`, which is exactly what we want: two different list items for two different authors.

Unfortunately, although the authors are now stored inside the PDF in an unambiguous way, both in the info dictionary and the XMP stream, Adobe Acrobat / Reader visualizes them in a rather awkward way:

```
"""Author 1""; ""Author 2"""; Author 2
```

This is not what one would expect, hence:

**You have two options:**

1. You apply the fix that can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/6737). In this case, you decide that the way Adobe Acrobat / Reader displays metadata is more important than the way the metadata is stored inside the PDF. As a consequence, you can't support PDF/A.
2. You decide that the internal structure of the PDF is more important than the way Adobe Acrobat / Reader displays the Authors and you tolerate the double quotes added by Adobe when it visualizes the metadata in the metadata dialog.

In any case: the quotes aren't added by iText(Sharp). When you look inside the PDF, there are no double quotes. The quotes are added by the PDF viewer, **not** by the PDF producer.